# Response as pretty object from executeQueryAsync

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

After successful execution of `context.executeQueryAsync(res, rej);` I have weird stuff in `res(response)` callback with weird object content as `{ $9_0: something, $bla_bla: anotherSomething}`. But I can clearly see pretty response of `ProcessQuery` response.

Code I have:

```
let context = new window.SP.ClientContext();            
window.Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setRating(
    context, 
    utils.extractGuid(item), 
    item.Id, 
    val);
context.executeQueryAsync(res, rej);
```

I don't want to use `.load()` `Item` to retrieve it's new property, but wanna extract it from response.

Is there way to serialize or retrieve proper things from response?

Example: `.setRating()`'s `ProcessQuery` returns new `avarageRating` as **5**
[image]
but callback of `Promise` returns strange looking object
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: That "strange looking object" is just SharePoints internal javascript variable notation :-)

Comment: Thanks, I see. And how to retrieve actually result of query? Should I use some constructor on it?

Comment: You have to make sure to load the element with context.load(), here is a MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: So there is no way to extract raw response, without storing item that I've changed etc in variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the private properties you should not mess with (*Microsoft can change the encoded names for any next version*)

Remember this is all (and fairly good) OOP Programming, that means you can't tinker with **Properties** from out side the Object

Check the .prototype chain (that `__proto__` in your screenshot) for available **Methods**  (better yet, check the documentation... but just checking the pc is often faster)

In the given example

[image]

The `get_id` , `get_displayName` , `get_hasUniqueRoleAssignments` are **Methods** (specific to this type of Object) you can use to access data values

The above is an Item as example

---

> In general with JSOM you have to use **Methods**; you can't get values from the Object yourself.

Comment: I don't have `item` as I didn't use `.load(item)` and simply called `Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setRating(context, utils.extractGuid(item), item.Id, val); context.executeQueryAsync(res, rej)`. That's all. I don't need any information about item, I just wanna retrieve response

Comment: You get a JSOM **Object** from the Server.. what that is depends on what you asked for. Objects have Methods that can give you the data ... OOP

Comment: Pity, but this Object don't have method `.showResponseAsItIs()`

Comment: So the proper way is actually do something like `item.get_item('avarageRating') -> Microsoft.setRating() -> context.load(item) -> executeQueryAsync()` and in callback `.get_item('avarageRating)` will be already updated?

Comment: I know the feeling, the Object of my love here doesn't have a "itsBeerOClockInAmsterdamGetMeOne" method... Is your question wrong? You want to update a Rating (and haven't checked the blogs)?  Handling a response can only be done after a **succesful** query, If you do the query syntax wrong, then there is no point in trying to understand a response (which in you case then could very well be an Error reply)

Answer (score 0):

Pity, but SharePoint pros do not allow to extract response as is, and only way to achieve expected result is to retrieve adjusted property by my own:

```
    let context = new SP.ClientContext();   
    let item = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(guid).getItemById(itemId);
    Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setRating(
        context, 
        guid, 
        itemId, 
        val);
    await new Promise((res, rej) => context.executeQueryAsync(res, rej));
    context.load(item);
    await new Promise((res, rej) => context.executeQueryAsync(res, rej));
    return item.get_item('AverageRating');
```